# Vscode intellisense error: variable "float32" is not a type name

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, intellisense, typedef

This following code produces error "variable "float32" is not a type name" in visual studio code.

```
typedef float float32;

typedef struct
{
  float32 real;
  float32 imag;
} cfloat32;
```

I have "c99" set as the cStandard in my c_cpp_properties.json (I have tired others as well). What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. It's just IntelliSense that doesn't realize that you've `typedef`ined `float32`. IntelliSense often gives these false problem indications. Ignore it and be happy as long as your code compiles clean.

Comment: Visual Studio and VS Code are buggy sometimes ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Although your code fragment is indeed completely conforming, I do suggest avoiding `typedef` in almost all circumstances.  Seriously, don't use it.  Also, you might be interested in knowing that since C99, C has built-in complex data types and arithmetic, and a library of complex functions (see complex.h).  You are likely to be better off using these than rolling your own.  For example, your `cfloat32` is much like the built-in data type `float _Complex`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I totally agree, however, in the land of embedded ecu drivers, this is the kind of code I have to work with :D

Comment: have you _selected_ the configuration where you defined `cStandard` to be the active one? It would be nice if you showed your c_cpp_properties.json